# Does the motion of centre of mass compatible with special relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity

Apparently, the special relativity theory is based on analyzing the motion of a point particle with relative speed near the speed of light. However, if I apply and combine this theory with a collection of particles with Newton's third law acting, is it correct to analyze the mass as a whole, whose dynamics equation is still modeled by F(net)=dmv/dt, where F(net) is the sum of all forces experienced by sub-particles within the system, and that m is modeled by [image]

Is this correct? If so, please provide reasonable reasons.

Comment: In relativity the notion becomes complicated. It is easy to see that there must be a frame of reference whereby the sum of momentum of everything in the system is zero, and that the energy of that system being boosted to any other momentum follows the Einstein energy-momentum relation. The centre of momentum frame is thus well defined. However, there are three different definitions of centre of mass in relativity (and quantum theory), and demons will eat you if you go near it. There is a LOT of literature on this topic.